# Test-Path command not working with two files to test

Tags: powershell

Am Testing a Path using the following commands.

```
    $IMLocation = C:\Test\
    $AppName = Test
    if (Test-Path  ($IMLocation + "$AppName\ - include $AppName.msi,$AppName.xml"))
```

The above code is returning "false", although i have both the files(msi,xml) in the 'IMLocation'. Not sure why? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$IMLocation = "C:\Test\"
$AppName = "Test"
if (Test-Path  -path "$IMLocation*" -include "$AppName.msi","$AppName.xml")
```

Comment: Small Change made it worked. I used 

    if (Test-Path  -path "$IMLocation\$AppName\*" -include "$AppName.msi","$AppName.xml")

Comment: @SenthilArasu Good! In my box I need to add the `*` to the path to make it work, I'm on a powershell v2.0..